# How to update and show results from database on C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm trying some exams with C# and creating a Student System. I have a little problems with visualization of table rows.

I created textboxes, where I should put the grades of the student. I put the values, but when I started again the app, the fields are empty. When I open table - the values are there. 
The other problem, after this is: If there was a grade in the textbox, and I want to change it, I won't to create another row in the table, I want to update the row for the current student. The communication between tables is the cell "id" and "Faculty Number".

**The procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].InsertGrades
    @fakNum nvarchar(50),  
    @math int,
    @physic int,  
    @pik int,  
    @oip int,  
    @saa int,
    @ps int,  
    @pmu int,  
    @kp int,  
    @asls int,
    @pe int
AS
    INSERT INTO [Grades] (FakNumber, Math, Physic, PIK, OIP, SAA, PS, PMU, KP, ASLS, PE)
    VALUES (@fakNum , @math, @physic, @pik, @oip, @saa, @ps, @pmu, @kp, @asls, @pe)
```

**Bool void:**

```
public static bool InsertGrades(Grade grd)
{
    GradesDataClassesDataContext grds = new GradesDataClassesDataContext();
    try
    {
        grds.InsertGrades(grd.FakNumber, grd.Math, grd.Physic, grd.PIK, grd.OIP, grd.SAA, grd.PS, grd.PMU, grd.KP, grd.ASLS, grd.PE);
        grds.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Another bool:**

```
public static bool InsertGrades(Grade g)
{
    if (g.Math > 6 && g.Math < 2 &&
        g.Physic > 6 && g.Physic < 2 &&
        g.PIK    > 6 && g.PIK    < 2 &&
        g.OIP    > 6 && g.OIP    < 2 &&
        g.SAA    > 6 && g.SAA    < 2 &&
        g.PS     > 6 && g.PS     < 2 &&
        g.PMU    > 6 && g.PMU    < 2 &&
        g.KP     > 6 && g.KP     < 2 &&
        g.ASLS   > 6 && g.ASLS   < 2 &&
        g.PE     > 6 && g.PE     < 2)

    {
        return UserData.InsertGrades(g);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**This must insert values from table to textboxes, *but it doesn't***:

```
private Data.Grade ReadStudentGrades()
{
    Data.Grade grd = new Data.Grade();
    grd.FakNumber = txtFakNumber.Text;
    grd.Math = Int32.Parse(txtMath.Text);
    grd.Physic = Int32.Parse(txtPhysic.Text);
    grd.PIK = Int32.Parse(txtPIK.Text);
    grd.OIP = Int32.Parse(txtOIP.Text);
    grd.SAA = Int32.Parse(txtSAA.Text);
    grd.PS = Int32.Parse(txtPS.Text);
    grd.PMU = Int32.Parse(txtPMU.Text);
    grd.KP = Int32.Parse(txtKP.Text);
    grd.ASLS = Int32.Parse(txtASLS.Text);
    grd.PE = Int32.Parse(txtPE.Text);
    grd.FakNumber = txtFakNumber.Text;

    return grd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this code:

> This must insert values from table to textboxes, but it doesn't:

```
private Data.Grade ReadStudentGrades()
{
    Data.Grade grd = new Data.Grade();
    grd.FakNumber = txtFakNumber.Text;
    grd.Math = Int32.Parse(txtMath.Text);
    grd.Physic = Int32.Parse(txtPhysic.Text);
    grd.PIK = Int32.Parse(txtPIK.Text);
    grd.OIP = Int32.Parse(txtOIP.Text);
    grd.SAA = Int32.Parse(txtSAA.Text);
    grd.PS = Int32.Parse(txtPS.Text);
    grd.PMU = Int32.Parse(txtPMU.Text);
    grd.KP = Int32.Parse(txtKP.Text);
    grd.ASLS = Int32.Parse(txtASLS.Text);
    grd.PE = Int32.Parse(txtPE.Text);
    grd.FakNumber = txtFakNumber.Text;

    return grd;
}
```

There is no way this code inserts values from table to textboxes. There isn't a single line in here that assigns a value to any textbox.

Perhaps you have it backwards?  Maybe it should be more like this:

```
private Data.Grade ReadStudentGrades()
{
    Data.Grade grd = new Data.Grade();
    txtFakNumber.Text = grd.FakNumber;
    txtMath.Text = grd.Math.ToString();
    txtPhysic.Text = grd.Physic.ToString();
    txtPIK.Text = grd.PIK.ToString();
    (txtOIP.Text = grd.OIP.ToString();
    txtSAA.Text = grd.SAA.ToString();
    txtPS.Text = grd.PS.ToString();
    txtPMP.Text = grd.PMU.ToString();
    txtKP.Text = grd.KP.ToString();
    txtASLA.Text = grd.ASLS.ToString();
    txtPE.Text = grd.PE.ToString();
    txtFakNumber.Text = grd.FakNumber;

}
```

Comment: Well, I tried this, but when I press the button, to add grades, all of the textboxes become with value "0" .. when I stop, and then start the program, the textboxes are empty. When I opened the table, there were the grades add, and the second row with the zeros on all grades.

Comment: I have code, which read studen info (like name, surname, faculty, course etc), so I used the same code for the grades, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well if you can't retrieve the data from the database, how on earth do you expect to be able to populate any textboxes?

Comment: I created class grades with some validations, and now the datebase saves values, but when I logout and then login, the textboxes are still empty.

Comment: That's because you need to retrieve the data from the database. If this is not clear to you then you are really missing the fundamentals here. Perhaps you should ask your instructor to explain.

Comment: I was wrote that I am new in this, but the moderator edited my post. I will start course after 1 month, but it is interesting to me and I started to train myself earlier.